# How to cross-compile a single python library for ARM

Tags: python, python-packaging

I'm trying to install [this spidev library](https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev) on a machine with an arm processor. It is already running python 3.5, but it does not have any build tools, and therefore can't install the package directly. I've found a lot of tutorials outlining how to build python for a specific architecture, but I just want to build a library. What is the most straightforward way to build the package for the arm architecture? I have the arm build tools on an x64 linux machine.

Thanks!

Comment: If it is a [pure-python](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#pure-python-wheels) library, you can build it as a wheel on a different arch that has the build tools installed and just copy it over. Do you know if that is the case?

Comment: @Arne It's not pure-python, it has a c backbone

Comment: then I'd need to test it to be sure.. in case your search didn't yield it, I'd try https://pypi.org/project/crossenv/ first and build wheels with `python -m pip wheel .` as the build command first, but that's just a guess on my part right now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install spidev on ARM architecture by building a wheel on x86.

On x86_84/AMD64 machine.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev
$ cd py-spidev
$ python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --plat-name=linux-aarch64
```

Copy the aarch64 wheel to arm machine.

On arm64 machine

```
$ python3 -m pip install spidev-3.5-cp310-cp310-aarch64.whl
```